# MS Access InStr Trim #FUNC! Null

Tags: ms-access, trim

Using Trim and InStr, I have written an MS Access query to extract data from a field. The query works as designed to extract the desired data, however I receive a `#FUNC!` error when the field I am extracting from is blank.

I have attempted nz and an IIF statement - neither worked.

Current code:

```
ExprA: Trim(Left([Target],(InStr(1,[Target],"=")-1)))
```

Any ideas on how to edit this query to prevent the `#FUNC!` error from appearing for blank/null values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "cheat" a little:

```
ExprA: Trim(Left([Target],(InStr(1,[Target] & "=","=")-1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `[Target]` contains `"="` with `IIF()`:

```
IIF(
  InStr(1,[Target],"=") > 0,
  Trim(Left([Target],(InStr(1,[Target],"=")-1))),
  [Target]
)
```

This code will return the whole `[Target]` column's value if `[Target]` does not contain `"="` and will not throw an error if the column is `NULL`.